# Gstreamer RTSP server pipeline with tee sticks

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

I'm building a gstreamer-rtsp-server that has a tee (when a client is connected). However, when a client connects, the `autovideosink` seems to only show one frame and sticks. Without the tee/autovideosink, it works. Why does it stick/freeze?

RTSP Server launch string: `videotestsrc pattern=ball ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, width=(int)800, height=(int)800, format=(string)I420 ! tee name=t !  x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96   t. ! autovideosink`

Client: `gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc protocols=tcp buffer-mode=1 location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test latency=0 ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! queue ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink sync=false`

Client output:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
0:00:20.123212962 22872 0x55f4a8b5e2d0 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5917:gst_rtsp_src_receive_response:<rtspsrc0> error: Could not receive message. (Timeout while waiting for server response)
0:00:20.123472189 22872 0x55f4a8b5e2d0 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:7548:gst_rtspsrc_open:<rtspsrc0> can't get sdp
0:00:20.123525806 22872 0x55f4a8b5e2d0 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5628:gst_rtspsrc_loop:<rtspsrc0> we are not connected
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Could not read from resource.
Additional debug info:
gstrtspsrc.c(5917): gst_rtsp_src_receive_response (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0:
Could not receive message. (Timeout while waiting for server response)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation notes, always use a `queue` after each `tee` branch:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/coreelements/tee.html?gi-language=c

> One needs to use separate queue elements (or a multiqueue) in each branch to provide separate threads for each branch. Otherwise a blocked dataflow in one branch would stall the other branches.

In your particular case, you should also add the `tune=zerolatency` option to the `x264enc` element. That is because the latency of `x264enc` by default is higher than the default queue sizes. Alternatively you need to increase the queue sizes to compensate for `x264enc`'s latency.